# Proof of Intermediate value theorem in non-standard analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, nonstandard-analysis

> A real function is continuous on $[a,b]$ such that either $f(a) > 0 >f(b)$ or $f(a) < 0 < f(b)$, then prove that $f(c) = 0$ for some $c \in (a,b)$.

---

**Proof :-**

We divide $[a,b]^*$ in $H$ equal parts, where $H$ is a positive infinite hyperinteger.

We get,

$$a, a +\delta, a+2\delta,\ ... \ , a+ H\delta = b$$

Let $a + K\delta$ be the last partition point at which $f(a+ K\delta) <0$,

Thus

$$f(a+K\delta) < 0 \le f(a+(K+1)\delta)$$

Since $f$ is continous $f(a+K\delta) \approx f(a+(K+1)\delta)$, thus $f(a+K\delta) \approx 0$,

Let $c = st(a+ K\delta)$

Therefore $f(c)= st(f(a+ K\delta)) =0 $

---

I have two questions,

1. Shouldn't it be $f^*(x)$ everywhere instead of $f(x)$ because a real function won't have a hyperreal number in its domain. Like it should be $f^*(a+K\delta) <0$ in the third line because $a+K\delta$ is not a real number it is a hyperreal number.
2. Why does $f(a+K\delta) \approx f(a+(K+1)\delta)$ ? Can't it be $f(a+K\delta) = 1000$ and $f(a+(K+1)\delta) = 2000$ ? Then those two are not infinitely close, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning 1, the convention is to delete the asterisk on functions but keep them on sets.  So whenever $f$ is applied to a nonzero infinitesimal or other hyperreal number not in $\mathbb R$, what is always meant is the natural extension ${}^\ast\! f$.

As for 2, the values of $f$ at have opposite sign at infinitely close points. Since the values are infinitely close, they must be infinitesimal by the triangle inequality. More precisely, $0\leq f(a+(K+1)\delta)\leq f(a+(K+1)\delta)-f(a+K\delta)$ which is infinitesimal by continuity. Therefore $f(a+(K+1)\delta)$ itself is infinitesimal.

Comment: Got the first one. About second, you say triangle inequality ? but where is the triangle ?

Comment: I fail to imagine the vertices.

Comment: To imagine them, draw a picture in an infinitesimal microscope as in Keisler. The three points are the values of the function at $a+(K+1)\delta$, $a+K\delta$, and the common standard part of the two points.

Comment: $0\leq f(a+(K+1)\delta)\leq f(a+(K+1)\delta)\color{red}{-}f(a+K\delta)$ that should be $"+"$, no ?

Comment: No it's a plus because the value of the function at $a+K\delta$ is nonpositive.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I thought I would never get an answer to this question because there is not love for NSA in this cruel world.

Comment: Yes there is!  We taught 150 students this year using Keisler and they were very satisfied; see [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.5642/jhummath.201701.07).

Comment: Keisler is a nice book but are there any pure Non-standard analysis book ? Keisler is calculus book. I want a analysis book like Rudin is for standard analysis.

Comment: There are many such books indeed!  One of the earliest is by Martin Davis.  Another good one is by Robert Goldblatt.  If you ask a separate question I can try to provide a more detailed list.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, there are atleast two or three more questions I will ask today!.

Comment: @A---B, by the way there is an interesting recent thread on Robinson's framework [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/265170/28128).

Answer (score 2):

For variety...

Because $f$ is continuous, the outer two equalities hold. Because $\delta$ is infinitesimal, the inner equality holds.

$$\operatorname{st}(f(a + K \delta))=f(\operatorname{st}(a + K \delta)) 
= f(\operatorname{st}(a + (K+1) \delta)) 
=\operatorname{st}(f(a + (K+1) \delta)) $$